# Creating Xpath for an Android element without ID in java

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, genymotion

I have been searching for this issue for a while so I decided to create an account and ask this myself. This is my first post so I'll do my best.

I want to fill three text fields in a certain screen. These fields do not have an id, index or content-desc. All the fields have the same class and package. The only detail they have is text.

I'm using Genymotion, Appium and Selenium.

This is my code:

```
package Steps;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MyStepdefs {

    AndroidDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "192.168.150.101:5555");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.contacts");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

So I want to add a new contact in my virtual device. I'm able to open the correct screen to add a new contact but now I need to fill in some text fields and this is where my problem starts.

I want to use the sendKeys method for the following field:
[Screenshot of UiAutomatorViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/371ib.jpg)

I tried the following Xpath:

```
MobileElement nameField = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']"));
    nameField.click();
    nameField.sendKeys("Test");
```

My Appium log:

```
    [HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']"}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']","e8c8c5fc-0dbc-42b5-835d-f27b0a365a95"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 15000 ms for condition
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']","context":"","multiple":false}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e8c8c5fc-0dbc-42b5-835d-f27b0a365a95/element - - ms - -
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/e8c8c5fc-0dbc-42b5-835d-f27b0a365a95
[HTTP] {}
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["e8c8c5fc-0dbc-42b5-835d-f27b0a365a95"]
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1530018954452 (15:15:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[Appium] Removing session e8c8c5fc-0dbc-42b5-835d-f27b0a365a95 from our master session list
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[ADB] Running 'D:\Handleiding\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 192.168.150.101\:5555 shell am force-stop com.android.contacts'
[ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[ADB] Running 'D:\Handleiding\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 192.168.150.101\:5555 shell input keyevent 3'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[ADB] Running 'D:\Handleiding\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 192.168.150.101\:5555 shell ps'
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Running 'D:\Handleiding\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 192.168.150.101\:5555 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionFinished' logged at 1530018960995 (15:16:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[W3C] Received response: null
[W3C] But deleting session, so not returning
[W3C] Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/e8c8c5fc-0dbc-42b5-835d-f27b0a365a95 200 6545 ms - 14
[HTTP]
```

I also tried the easy way, same result:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Name']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

And I even tried a List, same result:

```
List<AndroidElement> txtbox = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
txtbox.get(0).sendKeys("Test");
txtbox.get(1).sendKeys("0612345678");
txtbox.get(2).sendKeys("test@testtest.test");
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to my post so I can edit it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try defining your webdriver as AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  in both the declaration and the instantiation.  Also change the MobileElement to AndroidElement.  Your xpath looks correct to me.  Only other thing I can think of is that you are trying to access the element when that page is not loaded.

Comment: @BillHileman thanks for your quick reply. I tried your suggestion but I get the same results. I also added a sleep for 5 seconds just to check if it works but no luck either.

Comment: Are you sure it's getting to that particular screen?  You could also try `AndroidElement txtbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(text(), 'Name')]"));` in case there's maybe a hidden character in the text field.

Comment: I've taken a look at the contacts app on my emulator.  It's almost identical, probably a newer API, it has first and last name, not just name, but otherwise basically the same.  How are you getting to that page?  Can you show the steps you're taking between the time you initialize the driver and attempt to access the name field?

Comment: @Innoh you can use boundary values of the text boxes for your work.

Comment: @Innoh, from Appium logs it seems that it is not able to locate elements. You can try explicit wait for locating the elements or it might be the case that control is not on the screen where you are trying to locate elements.

Comment: @BillHileman sorry for the late reply. I tried your 2nd suggestion but it's not working either.

The steps I'm taking are: 
        driver.findElementById("com.android.contacts:id/floating_action_button").click();
driver.findElementById("com.android.contacts:id/right_button").click();
Thread.sleep(2000);

I click the add new contact button, click OK on the popup if I want to add it to my connected Google account. Those are the only steps I have to walk through to get to the add contact screen.

Comment: @Deepak I added a waitForElementPresent method to the test. Assuming that's what you meant? This also made no difference. I will try a different API now to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @BillHileman well I finally tried the latest Android version (API 26 instead of API 24) on my emulator and ran the exact same test and it worked perfectly. Can you add your comment as an answer so it can help people in the future? Thanks for your time and help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your webdriver as AndroidDriver in both the declaration and the instantiation.

Also change the MobileElement to AndroidElement.

Your xpath looks correct to me.